# RegEx: allow 1-25 letters or spaces but exclude three-letter-value-list

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm new to this forum and hope someone can support me.

I need to create a RegEx pattern which allows 1 to 25 letters or spaces but does not allow one of the values EMP, NDB, POI or CWR.

I tried the following using negative lookahead:

```js
((?!EMP|NDB|POI|CWR)[A-Za-z\s]{1,25})$
```

However this does not work properly, the value (like EMP) is still accepted - see https://regex101.com/r/YfflBi/1

This only works fine if I only have letters (no spaces) and limit down to 3:

```js
((?!EMP|NDB|POI|CWR)[A-Za-z]{3})$
```

(see https://regex101.com/r/SzmuwP/1)

However the challenge here is that I need 1 to 25 letters or spaces to be accepted but not one of the three-letter-values I mentioned.

Many thanks in advance to everyone thinking about a solution!

Comment: So what about "    EMP    " for example? Read: trailing/leading spaces?

Comment: This will not be the case, as we won't have " EMP ", we will only have "EMP"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:(?!EMP|NDB|POI|CWR)[A-Za-z\s]){1,25}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uPOkV1/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?!EMP|NDB|POI|CWR)[A-Za-z\s]` - a letter or whitespace that is not the starting char of the char sequences defined in the negative lookahead
- `){1,25}` - repeat the pattern sequence inside the non-capturing group one to 25 times
- `$` - end of string.